# React virtualized list dynamic width/height

Tags: javascript, react.js, typescript

I'm using [`react-window`](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-window) to virtualize a list. My list is supposed to fill in the container's completely and the container's width and height are 30vh and 100vh. Since the dimensions are dynamic and react-window requires me to provide constant dimensions, I'm hooking into the `onresize` event and updating the state of the component to pass the dimensions to the `FixedSizeList` component.

I was wondering if there was a better way to do this.

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react'
import { FixedSizeList } from 'react-window'
import InfiniteLoader from 'react-window-infinite-loader'

const MyList = () => {
  const { items, hasOlder, loadOlder } = mobxStore
  const divRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null)
  const [height, setHeight] = useState(divRef.current?.clientHeight || 800)
  const [width, setWidth] = useState(divRef.current?.clientWidth || 400)
  useEffect(() => {
    const handler = () => {
      const h = divRef.current.clientHeight
      const w = divRef.current.clientWidth
      if (height !== h) setHeight(h)
      if (width !== w) setWidth(w)
    }
    window.addEventListener('resize', handler)
    return () => window.removeEventListener('resize', handler)
  }, [])
  const itemCount = items.length + (hasOlder ? 1 : 0)
  return (
    <div className="items" ref={divRef}>
      <InfiniteLoader
        isItemLoaded={index => index < items.length}
        itemCount={itemCount}
        loadMoreItems={loadOlder}
      >
        {({ onItemsRendered, ref }) => (
          <FixedSizeList
            onItemsRendered={onItemsRendered}
            ref={ref}
            itemCount={itemCount}
            itemSize={60}
            height={divRef.current?.clientHeight || height}
            width={divRef.current?.clientWidth || width}
            overscanCount={10}
          >
            {({ index, style }) => {
              const item = items[index]
              if (!item) return <div className="loading" style={style}>Loading...</div>
              return <div style={style}>{renderItem(item)}</div>
            }}
          </FixedSizeList>
        )}
      </InfiniteLoader>
    </div>
  )
}

export default MyList
```

EDIT: Found out the library author recommends using `react-virtualized-auto-sizer` instead